# What coding language is silverlight itself written in?

Tags: silverlight

does anyone out there know what coding language silverlight itself is written in; C++, C#?

Comment: C++. Why does it matter?

Comment: i was curious if it was managed or unmanaged

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "Silverlight itself". Much of it - including the BCL - is managed code. Lower-level components - including the CLR - are unmanaged.

Comment: thank you kent for taking the time to help me learn something, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably written in C/C++, given that it's a browser plugin.

(Doing a scan of the binaries in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin` on my mac reveals a lot of libs with C linkage, which implement the minimal CLR required for code to run on top of Silverlight, but the plugin itself seems to be written in C/C++)

There are still managed libraries in the plugin bundle, as you'd imagine since it needs to be able to execute CLR assemblies, but it's unclear how much of the actual plugin logic is written on top of the mini-CLR provided.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is written in C++ for cross platform compatibility.